# Boot to black screen and cannot start grub to set nomodeset

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 7 on my laptop. It boots to a black screen and I'm pretty sure this is due to my nvidea graphics card. As numerous threads have pointed out I should boot with nomodeset. Following the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) I run into problems, namely, I cannot start Grub to select an entry and thereby cannot change "`quiet splash`" to "`nomodeset`".

If I press `esc` I am greeted instead with the following:

[image]

I tried `right shift` as well:

[image]

I also thought I could go through suggestion 2 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/452147). Problem here is that I never see the screen where I'm supposed to hit the `down` key. It just goes straight to the menu (so no selecting a language either). I Get the following menu and I cannot press `F6` (or F-anything) to bring up a menu where I can navigate to `nomodeset`. All options other than "advanced options" or "help" **immediately** lead to a perpetual black screen. This means that I **cannot** repair Grub via any [solutions offered here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

[image]

There's a list of boot parameters under help, including how to install with `acpi` off. But I read that's the nuke approach and I should only do that when all else fails, so am hoping there's an obvious boot command for setting `nomodeset` I'm not familiar with.

relevant specs:

```
GPU / Graphics
Technology
Single VGA support; up to 100W per
card; Modular MXM 3.0b;
Upgradeable
VGA / GPU Graphics
Options
8GB GDDR5; NVIDIA GTX 980M
(N16E-GX); 1536 CUDA;
GPU/VRAM Clock
1038MHz/2500MHz; Maxwell
(28nm); MXM 3.0b; 100W
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media.
Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop.
Start installation of the Ubuntu system.

When finished boot the installed system.
Highlight the **Ubuntu GRUB menu entry**.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu system.
Now first of all install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot ... you don't have to add a parameter anymore.

Comment: Pressing the E key while highlighting "try Ubuntu without installing" does nothing :(

Comment: @DirkHaupt : I never heard this before ... please use the up/down keys so that Try Ubuntu without installing is marked (highlighted) ... then press the E key ! :)

Comment: Pressing the tab key worked. From there I was able to edit quiet splash to nomodeset and get in, install, and then when I installed the nvidia drivers I got this issue: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283992 None of the solutions worked so I formatted everything and reinstalled Ubuntu and this time **I installed WITH an internet connection** and to my surprise just like that everything worked right after. I also checked and sure enough the laptop is using the nvidea card as a GPU. Moral of story: always install Ubuntu with an internet connection.